# WSO2-ESB 4.8.1 cluster with nginx. Worker node doesn't join

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have 3 nodes: nginx as third-party load balancer, 1 manager node, 1 worker node (just to test my setup and configs, you know). I'm doing all like in this tutorial:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+WSO2+Products+without+WSO2+ELB#ClusteringWSO2ProductswithoutWSO2ELB-Configuringthethird-partyloadbalancer So i'm starting my manager node, everything seems to be ok, i'm entering managment console successfully. And now i'm starting worker node like `sh ./bin/wso2server.sh -DworkerNode=true` , and i'm expecting to see in Managment Console's system logs or in Manager log something like "member joined". But I don't see. So where can be the problem? Worker starting without any error in logs. Maybe something is wrong about my nginx.conf?

> ```
> upstream wrk.esb {
>     server wrk.esb:9763;
> }
> server {
>     listen 80;
> server_name wrk.esb;
>     location / {
>         proxy_pass http://wrk.esb;
>     }
> }
> upstream ssl.wrk.esb {
>     server wrk.esb:9443;
> }
> server {
>      listen 443;
>  server_name wrk.esb;
>      ssl on;
>      ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/wrk.crt;
>      ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/wrk.key; 
>      location / {
>         proxy_pass https://ssl.wrk.esb;
>     }
> }
> server {
>     listen 443;
> server_name mgt.esb;
>     ssl on;
> #proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
> #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
> #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
>     ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mgt.crt;
>     ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mgt.key;
>     location /carbon {
>         proxy_pass https://mgt.esb:9443;
>     #proxy_redirect https://10.0.13.4:9443 https://mgt.esb  
>     #proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
>         #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
>         #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
>     #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;     
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> }

In fact, I can't see any line of code inside `wso2server.sh` script that can parse my `-DworkerNode=true` or `-Dsetup` input variales! So, there is no matter starting with `-DworkerNode=true` or `-Dsetup` - it's starting always like a manager...
I've found also nice article http://sajithswa.blogspot.ru/2015/01/blog-post.html. And it is confusing, but many things there are different from tutorial that i've mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved this problem. The deal was in that thing, that one must set `<parameter name="localMemberHost"></parameter>` in `axis2.xml` exactly as host, not ip. So, my manager's `axis2.xml` should have this line: `<parameter name="localMemberHost">mgt.esb</parameter>`, on worker in file `axis2.xml` this line:`<parameter name="localMemberHost">wrk.esb</parameter>` . And also it is necessary to set in `/etc/hosts`  both on manager and worker nodes this lines: `<ip_of_manager> mgt.esb` and `<ip_of_worker> wrk.esb`.